# MongoDB hidden node still receiving connections

Tags: database, mongodb, replicaset

I'm not sure if this question been asked before or if the following behavior of MongoDB is normal. Searching online output no results to this scenario.

Initially, we had a 3 node deployment, 1 Primary, 1 Secondary, and 1 Arbiter.

We wanted to add a ReadOnly replica to the cluster and remove the Arbiter node as well in the process. We added the following to the new node:

- priority: 0
- hidden: true
- votes: 1

And removed the Arbiter in the same reconfiguration process so we always have 3 voting members and it leaves us with 1 Primary and 1 Secondary and 1 ReadOnly Node.

The complete process went through smoothly, however, we still end up seeing connections to the ReadOnly replica.

But when checking via db.currentOp(), no queries show up.

Based on the documentation on MongoDB website,

> Hidden members are part of a replica set but cannot become primary and are invisible to client applications.

Is there a way to investigate why there are connections coming in? And if this is normal behavior?

**EDIT:** *(for further clarification)*

Assuming the following:

MongoDB A (Primary): 192.168.1.50

MongoDB B (Secondary): 192.168.1.51

MongoDB C (Hidden): 192.168.1.52

Client A: 192.168.1.60

Client B: 192.168.1.61

In the logs, we see the following:

```
2018-03-12T07:19:11.607+0000 I ACCESS   [conn119719] Successfully authenticated as principal SOMEUSER on SOMEDB
2018-03-12T07:19:11.607+0000 I NETWORK  [conn119719] end connection 192.168.1.60 (2 connections now open)
2018-03-12T07:19:17.087+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 192.168.1.60:47806 #119720 (3 connections now open)
2018-03-12T07:19:17.371+0000 I ACCESS   [conn119720] Successfully authenticated as principal SOMEUSER on SOMEDB
```

So if the other MongoDB instances were connecting, that would be fine, but my question is regarding why the clients are able to connect even when the hidden option is true and if that behavior is normal.

Thank You

Comment: A hidden secondary will have connections to other members of the replica set for replication and heartbeats. If you are seeing elevated connections (and not directly connecting to this hidden secondary), there is likely an explanation if you can provide further details. What specific version of MongoDB are you running (as reported by `db.version` in the `mongo` shell)? What is the output of `db.serverStatus().connections` on your hidden secondary? Lastly, are you including the hidden secondary in your connection string and if so, what MongoDB driver and version are you using?

Comment: @Stennie so the clients do not have this instance configured in their connection string since this instance was just launched and not yet provided to anyone. The DB Version is 3.6.3 and the connections it shows is 3 (which i understand could be due to the replication part)
But if i tail the mongo log file, i see successful authentications, new connections, etc being logged on the read only instance.

Comment: Are the source IP(s) for these connections other members of the replica set? If so, this sounds like normal replication activity. If there are connections from unexpected source IPs you should identify if those are expected (originating from application or internal IPs) or potentially due to a lack of security measures (see the MongoDB Security Checklist: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist). The information you have provided so far does not suggest anything unusual, but you are best placed to interpret the IP information for your deployment.

Comment: @Stennie added more clarification in the question. Hope that helps to clarify what I'm really trying to figure out.

Comment: What specific MongoDB driver and version are you using? Is the `SOMEUSER` noted in the log definitely a user from your application and not a manual connection? Are these connections always closed immediately after successful authentication? One more thought: would the hidden secondary happen to be on the same IP address and port as the former arbiter?

Comment: Looks like you posted a duplicate on DBA StackExchange (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199955/mongodb-hidden-node-still-receiving-connections) which is more on-topic than StackOverflow (programming Q&A). I'd close this question and update your DBA question with the driver details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more on-topic for DBA StackExchange and has been cross-posted there: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199955/mongodb-hidden-node-still-receiving-connections